# Don't see the screen that allows you to upload an SSL certificate even after scaling up my plan from D-1 (Shared) to B-1 (Basic)

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

I have an SSL certificate for my website.

I scaled up / upgraded by **Azure Service Plan** from **D-1 (Shared)** to **B-1 (Basic)** because that is the minimum plan required in order to have SSL bindings.

However, when I go to the **SSL settings** blade for my App Service, I do not see the screen that would allow me to upload my SSL certificate. Instead what I see is this screen.

[image: No screen to upload SSL certificate]

Which seems to suggest to me that I am still on a service plan that does not allow SSL bindings.

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the "Private Certificates (.pfx)" tab?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Yes, I'd done that, too and tried every other thing but couldn't mention it all in the question. I get a similar looking message like the one posted in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

It just took a whole bunch of time and I now see the screen to upload my SSL certificate.

Answer (score -1):

In the Azure portal, from the left menu, select App Services > .

From the left navigation of your app, select SSL settings > Private Certificates (.pfx) > Import App Service Certificate.

[image: Step 1]

Now that the certificate is imported, you need to bind it to a mapped domain name in your app. Select Bindings > Add SSL Binding.

[image: SLL Binding]

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of the process. I don't see the screens I am expecting. Starting with the screen to upload the certificate.

Comment: Your screenshot is binding tab. The next tab over on top of your image is Private Certificates (pfx)

Comment: I had tried them both and tried them all and they were the old screens that came with my previous plans. Took a few hours to update.